# {{#each}} in Handlebars and accessing each element created

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars to create a template for a table, and I can't seem to be able to access each individual td that is created.

```
<tbody>
                {{#each this}}
                <tr class='row'>

                        <td class='table-course'>{{name}}</td>
                        <td>{{teacher}}</td>
                        <td>{{department}}</td>

                </tr>
                {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

I have given the first td a class of 'table-course' however I can't seem to access these td's in jquery. When I try to trigger a jQuery event with $('td.table-course) nothing happens.

Does anyone know the best way to access these {{#each}} generated td?

Comment: What does the object you're passing in look like?

Comment: Does the table exist when you are trying to bind your event handlers?

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like?  Is it actually generating something?